# ng-init with razor expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, razor

I am trying to render the thing like this:

```
<thead ng-init="isDoctor = @(User.IsInRole("Doctor"))">
```

I expect it to be "isDoctor = true|false" (my server side code renders this template returning PartialView), btw I always get an error like: *Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [isDoctor =] starting at [isDoctor = at Error ()]*. So, what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<thead ng-init="isDoctor = @(User.IsInRole("Doctor") ? "true" : "false")">
```

Because C# boolean renders with capital first letter:

```
<thead ng-init="isDoctor = True|False">
```

And `True` or `False` is undefined

Comment: Great, it works. Damn, what an idiot mistake with upper-case. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you might consider the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    angular.module('my-module')
        .value('isDoctor', @(User.IsInRole("Doctor") ? "true" : "false"))
        // perhaps other values that need passed in from the server?
        .constant('aValue', '@Model.AValue') // for example
        ;

</script>
```

This doesn't put the value directly onto the scope like `ng-init` does; however, it gives you an injectable value that you can use in your controller, services, directives, etc. that is, effectively, a run-time configuration variable:

```
// some script somewhere
angular.module('my-module').controller('myController', [
    '$scope',
    'isDoctor',
    function($scope, isDoctor) {
        $scope.isDoctor = isDoctor;

        // other controller code here
    }]);
```

The nice part about this style of passing data from Razor to Angular is that Angular's dependency injection will throw an error if you forget to do this, since instantiating `myController` requires `isDoctor` to be defined. It moves what could potentially be a runtime error that's hard to find into a config/compile error that should be relatively easy to correct.

It also gives you a single place in your Razor (cshtml) file where your server-side parameters get passed into the Angular runtime, which is less messy, especially if your HTML markup has lots of directives and interpolation.

Comment: Yep, constant or value is also an option, unless there was no problem with ng-init, but 'undefined' values, taken from razor expression. Thx.

Comment: I'd not recommend following the suggested way because you can use Razor syntax only inside of .cshtml, not .js. Thus, you have to put your code inside of views I believe that's bad.